# How can I evaluate Excel functions in c# Console App?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-formula

I have to create a function in C# allowing to calculate Excel formulas entered in a string:

for example :

ROUND(COUNTIF(['YES', 'NO'],'YES')*(100/4),1)

I absolutely have to use a free library, but I can't find anything to do so in C#.

Has anyone come across this problem before ?

Thanks for your help

Explications of the app context :

This function receives as a parameter a string which has already been generated on another application over which I do not have control.

the need is to find a way evaluate this kind of string containing some Excel functions.

Comment: Excel functions that don’t reference any data? This seems a pretty bizarre use-case…

Comment: Why Excel specific? Those functions have native equivalents in C#. And why use `COUNTIF()` if not applied to a range of values? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I just added more informations about the context, the need is something like : https://formulajs.info/functions/ but in c# ..

Comment: It will really help a lot if you [explained why you need to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

[EPPlus v4](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) is LGPL. It can create Excel files but not execute them AFAIK. But you could [automate Excel afterwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c).

As [@DS_London](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13812982/ds-london) said: it is a weird use case, are you sure you got it right?